# Class Constructor error, class "classname" has no member "classname"

Tags: c++, class, constructor, header

```
#ifndef RESERVATIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define RESERVATIONS_H_INCLUDED
#include <vector>
#include <string.c>

class Reservations
{
public:
    Reservations::Reservations { }
    Reservations(string FullName, int PhoneNum);
    string getname() { return FullName; }
    int getnumber() { return PhoneNum; }
private:
    string FullName;
    int PhoneNum;
}

#endif // RESERVATIONS_H_INCLUDED

Reservations::Reservations(string FullName, int PhoneNum) //error on this line
{
    FullName = FullName;
    PhoneNum = PhoneNum;
}
```

I get the error in the title, I don't know why it's assuming I want it to have a member of it's own class...

Comment: What's `Reservations::Reservations { }` supposed to do?

Comment: `FullName = FullName;` is incorrect FYI

Comment: @sftrabbit It was supposed to be a default constructor, I just added it for the chance that it'd fix my error.

Comment: @Pubby Why is that? After reading some answers it is syntactically correct, with that staying the same.

Comment: @WillNasby to assign to member which has the same name as parameter, you need this pointer

Comment: ClassName::ClassName names the ctors. since at that time there were no ctors yet, the compiler rightfully came out with that error message.

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of problems with this code! Impressive to pack so many errors into so few lines.

Answer (score 2):

you included wrong header file

Change

```
#include <string.c>
```

to

```
#include <string>
```

Also use string with full namespace std.

below code should compile with minor fix:

```
class Reservations
{
public:
    Reservations() : PhoneNum(0) {}
    Reservations(std::string FullName, int PhoneNum);
    std::string getname() { return FullName; }
    int getnumber() { return PhoneNum; }
private:
    std::string FullName;
    int PhoneNum;
};

Reservations::Reservations(std::string FullName, int PhoneNum) 
{
   this->FullName = FullName;
   this->PhoneNum = PhoneNum;
}

// Better use member initializers list
Reservations::Reservations(std::string FullName, int PhoneNum) 
: FullName(FullName),
  PhoneNum(PhoneNum)
{
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, use constructor initializer lists to initialize the member variables.

Comment: The default constructor will leave `PhoneNum` uninitialized. Probably oughtta set it to 5551212 or 8675309 or something. 8v)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
Reservations::Reservations() { }
```

instead of

```
Reservations::Reservations { }
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
class Reservations
{
    public:
    //Reservations::Reservations { }
    Reservations() { }
    ....
```